# Index View not redirecting from another action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Controller action for download file. And after download I trying to redirect to Index view of the same controller. But it is not redirecting

here is my download Action

```
public ActionResult Download(MemoryStream docStream)
{
  byte[] bytes = docStream.ToArray();
                    docStream.Close();
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DocumentInfo.DocumentName + "");
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
                    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
return View("~/Views/DocumentDownload/Index.cshtml");
    }
```

Can any one help why it is not redirecting . Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not redirecting on index page. So where is it exactly redirecting? Is page showing error or something?

Comment: Hmmm, your method should just be a FileResult  and return a file, no ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: Share your Index action codes, maybe the problem occurs in there. Did you track your codes with breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the name "Index" inside view.
E.g.

```
return View("Index");
```